# How can I use Thunderbird to keep regular offline backups of my Gmail account?

Tags: backup, download, thunderbird, gmail, imap

I'd like to use Thunderbird to regularly download all the mail in my Gmail account via IMAP, so if something happened to Gmail or my internet connection is disrupted, I can still access all my mail.

My question is specifically about Thunderbird. Besides setting up the IMAP account, what else do I need to do in Thunderbird to ensure that all messages and attachments are synchronized locally as often as possible (not just when I "go offline" or manually synchronize).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Go to Tools / Options / Advanced / General / Config Editor

2) Search for mail.check_all_imap_folders_for_new and set to "true"

3) Go to Account Settings / Server Settings

4) Check 'Check for new messages at startup" and "check for new messages every x minutes"

5) Go to Account Settings / Synchronisation and Storage

6) Ensure "Keep Messages..." is enabled, with all folders checked in Advanced, and in Disc Space, "Synchronise all messages regardless of age"

Comment: Thanks. Found some more settings that should be set [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-gmail-google-data/).

Comment: Warning: This answer was already outdated when it was created. The new option to use since TB5 (release June 2011) is `mail.server.default.check_all_folders_for_new`. See http://kb.mozillazine.org/How_do_I_check_for_new_messages_in_other_folders